# Fuzzy sentence search in elasticsearch based on edit distance of words

Tags: elasticsearch

For a given index I have added documents like:

```py
[
{"expression": "tell me something about elasticsearch"},
{"expression": "this is a new feature for elasticsearch"},
{"expression": "tell me something about kibana"},
# ... and so on
]
```

Now, I want to query elastic search in a such a that for given input expression:
`"tell me something on elasticsearch"`. It must give out:

```py
{"expression": "tell me something about elasticsearch"},
{"expression": "tell me something about kibana"}
```

**Since it this case edit distance w.r.t. to `words` (not character level) is less in this case.**

Can we perform such a query on elasticsearch?

Comment: Do you want to exclude "this is a new feature for elasticsearch" doc? Show me your query.

Comment: I haven't written the query yet, but I want perform match_phrase with some fuzziness. Can it be achieved?

Comment: This [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-fuzzy-and-match-phrase/301386/2?u=rabbit_br) has similar question.

Answer (score 2):

as per my understanding fuzziness does not allow type phrase/match phrase.
But let me share few use cases for you and try if these are helpful.

1. If you want to perform search ignoring missing words use **slop** with match_phrase and not fuzziness(this may work for you)

   ```
   GET demo_index/_search
   {
       "query": {
           "match_phrase": {
               "field1": {
                   "query": "tell me something elasticsearch",
                   "slop": 1                                     -----> you can increase it as per your requirement
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Secondly if you want to perform search on character level changes you can use below queries with fuzziness

- Single search on different fields

  ```
  GET index_name/_search
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "enginere",                   -----> Wrong spelling but still we will get result wherever query match **engineer** keyword. Again you can increase fuzziness.
              "fields": [
                "field_name1",
                "field_name2",
                ...
              ],
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "slop": 1                              -----> not compulsory 
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Multi search in different fields

  ```
  GET index_name/_search
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "field1": {
                "query": "text1",
                "fuzziness": 1
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "field2": {
                "query": "text2",
                "fuzziness": 2
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "match": {
              "field3": "text3"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```